# Uncaught TypeError: obj.attr is not a function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required-input" value="test@yahoo.com">
```

```js
function validate(obj) {
    const email_regex = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    if (obj.attr("id") == "email") {
        regex = email_regex;
    }

    (!obj.val().match(regex) || obj.val().length == 0 || obj.val() == '') ? obj.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'): obj.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}

$('.required-input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('input keyup keypress blur change', function() {
         validate(this);   //EROR HERE
    });
});
```

The error is as follows `Uncaught TypeError: obj.attr is not a function`

Do you know the origin of this error?
It is wrong parameter function validated?

Please can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As `obj` is native DOM object you are getting the error. Convert it to jQuery object

```
$(obj).attr("id")
```

OR, Better pass jQuery object to validate function.

```
validate($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the DOMElement which you're attempting to call jQuery methods on - hence the error. You need to pass a jQuery object to the method instead. Try this:

```
validate($(this));
```